# else not executing in php

Tags: php, if-statement

If I leave all the fields blank, the code blow is not showing the else message.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="input_area" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea><br/><br/>
    Search<input type="text" name="find"/><br/><br/>
    Replace<input type="text" name="replace" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Find and replace"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['input_area'])&&($_POST['find'])&&($_POST['replace']))
{
    $text=$_POST['input_area'];
    $find=$_POST['find'];
    $replace=$_POST['replace'];

    if(!empty($text)&&!empty($find)&&!empty($replace))
    {
        $new_str=str_replace($find,$replace,$text);
        echo $new_str;  
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'FILL ALL THE FIELDS';     
    }
}
```

Comment: var_dump your variables, and see what they actually contain.

Comment: As @aynber stated. Place `var_dump($_POST)` above the code and see what it shows.

Comment: @aynber evrything is working fine when i'm inserting values, only else statement isn't working

Comment: @aman That's my point. If the else never happens, then you want to check your variables to see __why__

Comment: Actually, I take that back. You'll never get to that else because you're not going through the first if. Put the else with the first if, not the second.

Comment: @aynber its not working, the else part is showing along with the page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is the root of the problem

```
if(isset($_POST['input_area'])&&($_POST['find'])&&($_POST['replace']))
```

The correct one is

```
     if(isset($_POST['input_area'])&&isset($_POST['find'])&&isset($_POST['replace']))
```

Answer (score 1):

The values will be set in $_POST, but they will be blank. A check like this would work in all situations, even in some cases where someone has modified your html and tried something funny.

```
<?php
  $text = isset($_POST['input_area']) ? $_POST['input_area'] : "";
  $find = isset($_POST['find']) ? $_POST['find'] : "";
  $replace = isset($_POST['replace']) ? $_POST['find'] : "";

  if($text != "" && $find != "" && $replace != ""){
    $new_str=str_replace($find,$replace,$text);
    echo $new_str;  
  }else{
    echo 'FILL ALL THE FIELDS';       
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aman has a pretty good answer.  You may want to check if a user just entered spaces though.  Look up ctype_space($str) for that.  You could also adapt strlen for this purpose and trim to knock off whitespaces that may appear at the beginning or end of the input (or all of it)... if you want your code structure to look the same.

```
if (  strlen(trim($_POST['input_area']))>0 && etc.
```